# Encode multiple files from the same Folder with Google Colab & FFmpeg

Tags: python, loops, ffmpeg, directory, google-colaboratory

i made a Google colab to encode my videos, but actually i can only do files on by one.
I want to encode all video files from the same folder.

I tried this but didn't seem to works

```
    import os

DIRECTORY= '/content/drive/My Drive/Videos'
for filename in os.listdir(DIRECTORY):
    if (filename.endswith(".mov")): #or .avi, .mpeg, whatever.
        os.system("ffmpeg -i {0} -c:v libx265 -crf 26 -c:a aac -b:a 160k output%d.mp4".format(filename))
        print(filename)
```

Edit: I edited the FFmpeg command but still not workings on Google Colab.
Edit 2: Print command only return the name of the files with the extension like "MyMovie.mov" how do i put the full path to the ffmpeg command? I also want to put the ouput files to a subfolder named x265

Comment: You're using a sequential pattern for the output file name (`output%d.mp4`). This only works for image outputs and the segment muxer. But you don't want either of those. I'm guessing you want something more like `output/{0}` (but note that I don't use python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os, sys, re

input_folder= '/content/drive/My Drive/Videos'
output_folder= '/content/drive/My Drive/Videos/X265' 
quality_setting = '30'
file_type = 'mp4

my_suffixes = (".mp4", ".mov", ".mkv", ".avi", ".ts", ".flv", ".webm", ".wmv", ".mpg", ".m4v", ".f4v")

from pathlib import Path
Path(output_folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

for filename in os.listdir(input_folder):
   if (filename.endswith(my_suffixes)):
       cmd = !ffmpeg -v quiet -stats -hwaccel cuvid -i "$input_folder/{filename}" -metadata comment="X265-QF$quality_setting-AAC" -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset:v slow -rc vbr -cq $quality_setting -c:a aac -b:a 160k "$output_folder/Seting1{filename}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using your code and the Python part seems fine. With FFmpeg it is very convenient to have a way to check the output of your commands, you should check it everytime your program doesn't behave the way you want it to.

So I checked the FFmmpeg output in my terminal and everything seemed fine. Indeed, your command works perfectly but might not be the command you want.
The command you typed outputs one image from the input file. So it does not encode a video.

You're not very clear on what you want to do but I'll try to guess:

- If you want to encode a video from images you should use such command

> ffmpeg -r 24 -f image2 -i PATH_TO_FOLDER/frame%d.png PATH_TO_FOLDER/output.mp4

So here you specify your framerate (24 is not compulsory) with -r and your input format with -f (which are images in this case)
This [link](https://hamelot.io/visualization/using-ffmpeg-to-convert-a-set-of-images-into-a-video/) might help in this case.

- If you want to separate the frames from a video (which is the closest to your command):

> ffmpeg -i PATH_TO_FOLDER/video.mp4 PATH_TO_FOLDER/frame%d.png
> In this case, this [link](https://averagelinuxuser.com/convert-video-to-images-with-ffmpeg-in-linux/) might help.

In both cases you could want to 0-pad the numbering in your filenames for future use of the frames, it is explained [there](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence). The later link is broader than the before but it must cover your usecase of FFmpeg.

Comment: Thank you for you help but by mistake i put the wrong ffmpeg command on the original post.

Comment: Do you have the output of the FFmpeg command?
Did you install FFmpeg on google colab? (tutorial there : https://colab.research.google.com/github/yunooooo/FFmpeg-for-Google-Drive/blob/master/FFmpeg.ipynb#scrollTo=CUq1_Dnegrs1)

Comment: Yes FFmpeg is installed on my Google Colab, and it's actually works when i use it only for one file. But when i try to do it for a folder (with the OP command) i get no output at all.

Comment: Maybe you've already done it but you should check your paths. You said that the print outputs the good path so the input path should be correct but your output path (here output.mp4) is simply the filename so depending on where your shell is executing it might be saving the file elsewhere. Try using `DIRECTORY + "/output.mp4"` instead of  `output.mp4`

Comment: I tried this but still no luck, the print output only return the filename with extension (mymovie.mov) but not the path